# CentOS 5.8 dig is not resolving ip-address

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, dig

I'm running centos 5.8 on a local machine at home. Today I was trying to analyze the DNS-Lookup via dig.

```
$ dig +trace -t A www.heise.de.
```

This is giving me something like this as a response

```
de.         172800  IN  NS  f.nic.de.
de.         172800  IN  NS  z.nic.de.
de.         172800  IN  NS  s.de.net.
de.         172800  IN  NS  n.de.net.
de.         172800  IN  NS  a.nic.de.
de.         172800  IN  NS  l.de.net.
;; Received 344 bytes from 192.58.128.30#53(192.58.128.30) in 49 ms
```

In contrast my dedicated CentOS machine is returning the following

```
 de.            172800  IN  NS  a.nic.de.
 de.            172800  IN  NS  n.de.net.
 de.            172800  IN  NS  f.nic.de.
 de.            172800  IN  NS  z.nic.de.
 de.            172800  IN  NS  l.de.net.
 de.            172800  IN  NS  s.de.net.
 ;; Received 344 bytes from 192.58.128.30#53(j.root-servers.net) in 32 ms
```

As you can see, the last line is different. Any idea why my dedicated machine is giving me the host name of the responding DNS-Server and my local machine is only returning the ip-address?

Thanks in advance

*UPDATE*

The reverse DNS-Lookup is working without any problems. Also, I just checked this on my local mac and...exactly the same problem occurs. Is it possible that this has to do with the local router/modem/ISP?

Comment: Maybe it's simply a `dig -v` issue ?

Answer (score 2):

If the reverse lookup fails on one machine but succeeds on the other, then the problem is probably just a difference in the machines' resolv.conf. Perhaps you have a 'search' or 'domain' field specified in the second machine's resolv.conf, or perhaps you are using different nameservers all together. What is your DNS setup like? You said you're at home; does this mean you are just using external DNS like google or your ISP, or do you have your own local DNS?

Comment: The reverse lookup is working on my local box. I'm using the ISP default DNS.

Comment: Very very strange. I just checked this on my mac and...exactly the same problem occurs. Is it possible that this has to do with the local router/modem/ISP?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between them is nothing more than a reverse-lookup on the IP address that returned the response.

Can you do the reverse lookup yourself from your local box?

```
dig -x 192.58.128.30
```

If this fails, that's the reason.

Comment: The reverse lookup from my local box is working. Any other ideas?